# Modeling JSON with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Using C# I've modeled a JSON message this way:

```
public class MessageBase<T>
{
    public MessageBase() { this.message = new List<T>(); }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<T> message { get; set; }
}

public class LogonRequest
{
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}

MessageBase<LogonRequest> logon = new MessageBase<LogonRequest>()
{
    id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    type = "Logon"
};

logon.message.Add(new LogonRequest() {userName = "user", password = "123"});

var message = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(logon);
```

I'm a JavaScript beginner and trying to do something similar as my C# code but this is the best I've come up with so far. Is there a more standard way to define this message structure and reuse it using JavaScript?

```
var messageObj = {id: 123456789, 
                  type: 'Logon',
                  message:[{username:'user', password:'123' }]
                 };

var message = JSON.stringify(messageObj);
```

Comment: You could make a class in JS for the Message object, but you really don't need to. I'd say a simple object like what you've got is all that you'll really need for this. Something like that is fairly standard.

Comment: The way you're doing it *is* the standard way.

Comment: It will not get better than this. Maybe you are interested in Typescript: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get some of the same behavior from Javascript, with the caveat that Javascript is not a typed language, which reduces your options of modeling things.

One concept that makes your C# models `MessageBase<T>` and `LogonRequest` possible is the concept of classes which is built into the language. Unlike C#, vanilla Javascript does not have a concept of class, and even in ES6 with the `class` keyword, it pays to understand the semantic differences between Javascript's prototype inheritance and the class of a first-class object-oriented language.

First, a syntax example of those models using pre-ES6 Javascript:

```
function Message(id, type, list) {
  this.id = id;
  this.type = type;
  if('undefined' === typeof(list)) {
    this.message = [];
  } else { this.message = list; }
}

function LogonRequest(userName, password) {
  this.userName = userName;
  this.password = password;
}

var logonRequest = new LogonRequest('user', '123');
var messageObj = new Message(123456789, 'Logon', logonRequest);
var message = JSON.stringify(messageObj);
```

In the above example, the functions `LogonRequest` and `Message` are called the "the constructor" of those classes, and the `this` inside those functions is the `this` context that is in place where the function is called (check out [a relevant explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/1435756) for more info about how `this` works). This makes it important to use the `new` keyword, as is done on the following lines, which creates a new object context to which the `this` applies.

ES6 improves this syntax somewhat, giving us the following equivalent form:

```
class Message {
  constructor(id, type, list) {
    this.id = id;
    this.type = type;
    if('undefined' === typeof(list)) {
      this.message = [];
    } else { this.message = list; }
  }
}
```

But its use and inner-workings are exactly the same as above.

It is worth noting that some developers do not like this aspect of Javascript, and prefer a more strongly-typed syntactic expression as C# provides. This is what accounts for the advent of a number of languages that transpile to Javascript, most notably Typescript, which allows a syntax very similar in semantics to your C# example.